# How to stop a certain window from minimizing?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

I have developped a stock shares excel workbook that automatically updates through out the day by downloading the new rates, etc...

I would like to keep it on one of my secondary monitors in full screen, so I can keep and eye on it easily without needing to switch to it.

The problem is that whenever I press Win+D to minimize the other applications I have on my primary monitor, my share Excel workbook gets minimized as well, which is of course the correct behaviour.

What I am after is may be a free/shareware that is able to block some windows from getting minimized?

A google search didn't help really much. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Always On Top Maker](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm). It's freeware and only 6 KB. The instructions are explained in the link I gave.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to just allow to set it on top, not prevent it from being minimized, right?

Comment: @Kharlos Dominguez: That's right.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [DeskPins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html). Its free. I have used it for a while now and had no problems with it.

Comment: Again, thanks, but it seems to just allow to set it on top, not prevent it from being minimized, right?

Comment: You are right - I just tested it. Sorry.